# Text parsing with VB in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

Using word 2007, I need to parse text in a document.

The text is in the form:

```
<number>. <question_text>
a. <answer1_text>
b. <answer2_text>
c. <answer3_text>
d. <answer4_text>
e. <answer5_text>
Answer: <correct_letter>. <feedback_text>
```

It needs to be outputted in this form:

```
<number>) <question_text>
~Y. <feedback_text>
a. <answer1_text>
b. <answer2_text>
*c. <answer3_text>
d. <answer4_text>
e. <answer5_text>
```

The answer who's letter is the correct_letter needs to have a * in front of it.

There are multiple questions in a given document. Any help towards a VB solution will be appreciated. I figure the solution involves looping through each line in the document, looking for each variable, and once all variables are found, output them in the correct formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like using Word as your database...which is not my skillset.

But I know Word works with XML now -- if you converted it to XML, it would then at least be queryable...  From there you could use XSL Transformations.